How to pass request parameters to an Angular component in SSR (Angular 18) and view logs in the browser?
I am working with Angular SSR (Server-Side Rendering) in Angular 18, and I need to pass the request parameters (e.g., headers, protocol, etc.) to my component. I am able to log the request object in the terminal during server-side rendering, but I cannot see the logs in the browser's console.
Here's how I'm currently passing the request parameter to the component:
Server-Side Code:
javascript

server.get('**', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('here');
  const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

  commonEngine
    .render({
      bootstrap: AppServerModule,
      documentFilePath: indexHtml,
      url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
      publicPath: browserDistFolder,
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
        { provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: req },
        { provide: 'ORIGIN', useValue: 'example.com' }
      ],
    })
    .then((html) => res.send(html))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
});

Component Code:
typescript

constructor(
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  private businessService: BuisnessService,
  private location: Location,
  private router: Router,
  @Optional() @Inject("REQUEST") private request: any,
  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
) {
  console.log('req.headers', this.request);
  this.getDomainInfo();
}

Problem:

I can see the request object logged in the terminal (during SSR) but not in the browser console.
I know that I can use isPlatformBrowser to conditionally execute browser-side logic, but the page source shows nothing in the HTML response which comes frrom api. I need to access the request object in ts file to get hostname and send it to api to get the response and render it on html file


The server config doesn't work in devMode in v18. The best is to update to v19, which addresses this issue.

@MatthieuRiegler does that mean it will work if i deploy it and then test it?

In v18, yes that should work.

Can i not run locally using prod build or prod mode @MatthieuRiegler
